# React componentDidMount execute before render

Tags: reactjs

In render added something simple:

render() {
return (
< div id="div-id-content">
test123
< /div>
);
}
}

In componentDidMount is added:

alert("test");

So alert show first but view of page is empty or awry. It's depend on browser. And after "alert" clicked  button "ok" - the view are load. This is bug or maybe I missunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct. In any class based component the render() function runs first and then the componentDidMount() function. I have attached a code sandbox link that clearly shows from the console.log() statements that render is executed first.

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-snowflake-0kh9s?file=/src/App.js

If you have further doubts, I suggest you post a codesandbox link here trying to reproduce the error you are getting so I can solve it better